# jQuery - Get Elements of Object Housed in .val()

Tags: jquery

If `.val()` gives me a string representation of the following:

```
{
   "dept_catg_grp_nbr":"239",
   "dept_catg_grp_desc":"TABLE TOP GROUP"
}
```

How do I access the individual elements?

Comment: `.val()` doesn't give you that and that is it.

Comment: why the heck are people downvoting this question? I don't understand.

Comment: this is the second time he posted about the same issue.

Comment: Actually it's not the same issue. Similar, but completely different question.
$.parseJSON is what I was missing.

Comment: @user3352316 Based on your comment, updated the question to clarify that `val` is giving you a string representation of that as `val` cannot return objects directly.  If you feel the edit is inaccurate feel free to revert my change.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var val = $.parseJSON($obj.val()).dept_catg_grp_desc;
```